# Simple Java Client to connect to a Sonic Topic

Tags: java, jndi, jms-topic, sonic

I need to write a simple java class which send messages to a Sonic Topic. I can use the JNDI values for lookup.
Here is the code.

```
Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<>();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.MFContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://Devserver:7002");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
properties.put("com.sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.domain", "dmDEV");
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");
Topic topic = (Topic) jndiContext.lookup("testtopic");
```

This throws an error
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: /testtopic not found in the specified context

When I debug the code, I can see "connectionFactory" variable has following fields and values which are totally different from the values I specify above in properties.

```
brokerHostName  "MyMachine" (id=55) 
brokerPort  0   
brokerProtocol  "tcp" (id=59)   
brokerURL   "" (id=66)  
clientID    null    
connectID   null    
defaultPassword "" (id=67)  
defaultUserName "Administrator" (id=68)
```

I need to know how to write a simple Java client to connect to a Sonic topic.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following which resolved my issue. Here is it in case you face the same issue. topic = session.createTopic(topicName);